# WiX Patch dialog - background image not shown

Tags: installation, wix, patch

I have created an working WiX Patch but during it's installation it does not show the product background image.

The original product setup dialog shows the images and they are defined in it's project like:

```
<Product ...>
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="gn_setup_dialog_banner.bmp" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="gn_setup_dialog.bmp" />
```

The patch is created and works fine. The problem is that it does not show these images. It shows some default background for the dialog.

Here is my patch if this helps:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
    <Patch AllowRemoval='yes'
        Manufacturer='xxx'
        MoreInfoURL='...'
        DisplayName='...'
        Description='Small Update Patch'
        Classification='Update'
        Codepage="...">

        <Media Id='5000' Cabinet='RTM.cab'>
            <PatchBaseline Id='RTM' />
        </Media>        

        <PatchFamily Id="HotFixPatchFamily" Version="1.0.1.0" Supersede="no" />
    </Patch>
</Wix>
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the patch was delivering these two files as "new" ones...even tough they were not changed.

Anyway, I solved the problem by replacing the stock Wix dialog images, like it is suggested here (at bottom "Replacing the stock bitmaps"):

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/WixUI_dialog_library.htm